# Sending a message to everyone in a discord server

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my discord bot to send a message to everyone on my discord server, all the answers I've tried haven't worked for me. I have this code so far but don't know if it works as I don't have anybody on discord (I'm making it for a friend)

here is the code:

```
    import discord

    def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

    token = read_token()

    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
         if message.content.find("!hello") != -1:
         await message.channel.send("Hi") # If the user says !hello we will 
         send back hi

      if message.content.startswith('Message everyone'):
      for guild in client.guilds:
          for discord.Member in guild.members:
            await message.discord.Member.send("sup")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Are you trying to send a DM to all the users or just trying to mention everyone like `Hello @everyone`?

Comment: I am trying to send a dm to all users in a server. I'll post the updated code i have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [create_dm()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.create_dm) to create a dm for a member.

Added in a check to skip any bots.

Using `lower()` for the message to handle any case.

FYI - it is pretty simple to create guilds in discord, so you can test, if you can't test it really isn't worth attempting.

Try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.find("!Hello") != -1:
        await message.channel.send('Hi')
    if message.content.lower().startswith('message everyone'):
        for guild in client.guilds:
            await sleep(.25)
            members = guild.members
            for member in members:
                if member.bot is True:
                    continue
                await sleep(.25)
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                await channel.send('sup')
```

Comment: for the sleep function, sleep = discord.utils.sleep? I also meant i don't have any other people in my server atm to see if another person got a dm

Comment: For sleep using asyncio - `from asyncio import sleep`. Got it on the testing. I created another user and have one user signed into the app and the other on a browser.